# Topology and Arithmetic Progressions

Tags: general-topology

I'm self-studying from "Elementary Topology Problem Textbook" by O.Ya.Viro et al. This is Exercise 2.Lx :

> Consider the following property of a subset $F$ of the set $\mathbb{N}$ of positive integers: there is $n$ ∈ $\mathbb{N}$  such that $F$ contains no arithmetic progressions of length $n$. Prove that subsets with this property together with the whole $\mathbb{N}$ form a collection of closed subsets in some topology on $\mathbb{N}$.

My line of thought so far:

I will need to demonstrate that the arbitrary intersections and finite unions of these closed sets yields a set that does not contain a progression of length $n$. This is easily seen for the arbitrary intersection argument, since if the resultant set contains a progression of length $n$, so must have each of the sets that were involved in the intersection.

I am unable to demonstrate that finite unions of such sets do yield sets without the a progression of length $n$, and I believe I have constructed a counterexample.

For if I had one such "closed set" $A$, I could add a fixed number $k$ to each of its elements to yield a different set (for a suitable $k$) which too does not contain a progression of length $n$. And the union of $n$ such "closed" sets would yield a set that contained a progression of length $n$.

Am I missing something somewhere?

(The book also indicates that Van Der Waerden's theorem might be needed:
For every $k$ there exists $N$ such that either $A \subset ${$1, ... N$} or {$1, ... N$}\ $A$  contains a an arithmetic progression of length $k$.
I have thus far been unable to apply it effectively.)

Comment: A counterexample should be concrete, if possible. Can you write down two sets explicitly?

Comment: Note that $n$ depends on the set. If $F_1$ contains no progression of length $n_1$ and $F_2$ contains no progression of length $n_2$, then $F_1\cup F_2$ contains no progression of length $n_3$, where $n_3$ might be a lot larger than $n_1$ and $n_2$.

Comment: Say no progressions of length 4 are allowed, so {1,2,4,8} would be an admissible set. So would {10,11,13,17} {19,20,22,26} and {28,29,31,35} (I'm adding 9 to avoid possible repetitions). Their union would contain the progression 1,10,19 and 28, which is of length 4.

Comment: But it doesn't contain one of length 5, say, so it's still closed... The $n$ depends on the set, and is not fixed...

Answer (score 1):

You seem to have overlooked that the property defining closed sets begins with "*there is* $n\in\mathbb N$ such that ..."  So, when you've enlarged a closed set by adding enough points to make an arithmetic progression of the length equal to the particular $n$ that you had in mind, that set might well fail to contain any arithmetic progressions of some greater length $n'$.  If so, that set would again be closed according to the definition.

Comment: Wow, I knew I was missing something crucial. I can now see that it is immediately true for unions of finite sets, since there can be no progressions of length greater than the cardinality of the union, and that a set that is not closed must have progressions of every length. Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

if $A$ and $B$ are closed sets then $\exists n_A, n_B$ such that no AP in $A$ has length $\gt n_A$ and no AP in $B$ has length $\gt n_B$. if $A \cup B$ were not closed then we could find a progression in $A \cup B$ of length $N$ such that the corresponding $k_N$ from van der Waerden's lemma (after a simple transformation) satisfies $k_N \gt \max(n_A,n_B)$

Comment: Thank you so much. It took me sometime, but now it's all very clear.

Comment: nice question. van der Waerden's result looks tricky to prove!

Comment: I'd like to further my understanding of your answer (what seemed clear a few minutes back is suddenly falling apart): Assuming the union is not  closed, it must contain APs of every length. Now, for some k> max($n_a$,$n_b$); we can find the corresponding N for which {1 ... N} is guaranteed to have an AP of length k. Are we now trying to color this set with A and B (with respect to whether they belong or not) and then noticing that there must be an AP of either of these colors > $n_a$ or $n_b$? How do I deal with the numbers not either of the sets?

Comment: I must clarify that I am using the Wiki's formulation of [Van der Wareden's theorem](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Van_der_Waerden%27s_theorem).

Comment: Your original answer chose $k_n$> 2*max($n_a$,$n_b$). I understand that now. Was there anything wrong with it?

Comment: my thinking was that if $A \cup B$ contains an AP of length $n$ then this is $\{a+bk | k \in \{0,...,n-1\}\}$, so we have subsets $A',B' \subset \{0,...,n-1\}$ satisfying $A' \cup B' = \{0,...,n-1\}$. it is to this situation that the lemma can be applied